# django_countries in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-countries

I am trying to create an API which can return all the countries using django_countries.

I am trying something following but it is not working. As an individual field, it works fine but with complete countries list it is giving an error.

```
from django_countries import countries


class CountrySerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    country = serializers.ListField(source=countries)
    class Meta:
    fields = ("country",)
```

Comment: What is the error,show us your code and full traceback of the error.

Comment: Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'Countries' object has no attribute 'split'
Exception Location:

Answer (score 4):

You can user serializer_fields in django_countries.

Like This:

```
from django_countries.serializer_fields import CountryField

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country = CountryField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Person
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'country')
```